# PyAudio duplicate devices

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying to list my audio devices, but PyAudio is showing some duplicate devices, i think.

Here is the result(2 and 6, 4 and 5):

```
1. {'type': 'input', 'name': 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input'}
2. {'type': 'input', 'name': 'Microphone (Realtek High Defini'}
3. {'type': 'output', 'name': 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output'}
4. {'type': 'output', 'name': 'Speakers (Realtek High Definiti'}
5. {'type': 'output', 'name': 'Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)'}
6. {'type': 'input', 'name': 'Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)'}
```

This is my code:

```
def get_devices(self):

    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    devices = {}

    for x in range(self.p.get_device_count()):
        d = self.get_device_info(x)
        devices[x] = { 'name' : d['name'] , 'type' : 'output' if d['maxInputChannels'] == 0 else 'input' }

    return devices
```

The duplicate device has the name cutted. What is wrong with my code. Or this is a bug?

I'm using MS Windows 8.

Comment: For people that don't have pyaudio, how does `d` look?

Comment: d looks like:
{'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 
    'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.0, 'index': 5, 
    'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.0101587, 
    'name': 'Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)', 
    'structVersion': 2, 'hostApi': 1, 
    'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.003, 
    'maxInputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0}

Comment: Have you tried printing `d['name']` each iteration in the `for` loop? If the names look correct, it may be an issue with you code, if not the issue is in the library `pyaudio`.

Comment: The issue could be with the Realtek drivers (e.g., maybe you have old Windows 7 drivers which happen to sort of work in Windows 7 but have a few glitches). Or it could even be not a problem at all, but the fact that the speakers intentionally show up as two separate devices for some useful reason (e.g., so you can choose between two different ways of mapping 5.1 to 7.1+2). Can you check whether you have up-to-date drivers? And whether the device shows up twice in the Windows control panel?

Comment: Yes, all my drivers are up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not duplicates. Some of them probably come from MME hostApi, some other may come from DirectSound hostApi, some other may come from Windows-KS, or WASAPI, or even ASIO.

I had the same situation, and I chose to keep from this device list only those coming from DirectSound and ASIO (when on Windows).
You can filter the list with the key "hostApi" for the dict  (0=mme, 1=directsound, etc. please check in the pyaudio doc).

Comment: Ok. When you have verified, please tell me if it was the reason, because I'm also interested about the solution of your question.

Comment: That's worked fine. I'm using ASIO, Windows DirectSound and Windows WASAPI. Windows WDM-KS and MME aren't good, they had many devices. For Linux I'm using ALSA.
Native APIs overview in http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html